# Find the dimension of the vector space with the following condition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I have the following here:

Find the dimension of the vector space:

$V=\{p(x) \in \mathcal{P}_2 | xp'(x)=p(x)\}$

If I let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, this implies $x(2ax+b)=ax^2+bx+c$ or $2ax^2+bx=ax^2+bx+c$

So that means: $ax^2-c=0$

But that's the same thing as:

$ax^2-1(c)=0$

So we have the basis vectors $\{x^2,1\}$. Does that mean the dimension is $2$?

I just want to be sure about my work.

Comment: $1$ is not in your vector space.  Neither is $x^2$.

Comment: I see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You you did proves that your space consists of those $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ such that $a=c=0$ ($ax^2-c$ is the null polynomial if and only if $a=c=0$). So, your space is $1$-dimensional, since it consists of the multiples of $x$.